# Do we get CORS issue if we are calling the API using RestTemplate from java service?

Tags: java, cors

Do we get CORS issue if we are calling the API(end point ) using RestTemplate from java Service?

Answer (score 1):

> Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows
> restricted resources on a web page to be requested from another domain
> outside the domain from which the first resource was served.
>
> The specification for CORS is included as part of the WHATWG's Fetch
> Living Standard. This specification describes how CORS is currently
> implemented in browsers.

CORS is only implemented in browsers. So if you don't emulate any browser and just use RestTemplate java client, then you shouldn't worry about CORS.

But if you write end-to-end testing scenarios, using tools like Selenium, then you will be able to reproduce CORS-related behaviour, using correspondent selenium browser drivers.

Answer (score -1):

If your service does not return `Access-Control-*` headers, you will get a CORS error in a browser.
If you need more info, there is a good article from Mozilla about CORS:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS